# Save the reference $(this) to DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, this

I'm not sure how to ask this question correct since my understanding of the DOM is lacking.

What I'm trying to do is to catch any click event on any given DOM element. I then want to save the element type as well as the complete reference to element in a Database. But  I'm not sure this is at all possible?

What i want to achieve is to save a hole interaction with a web app, in a way so you can later replay every action performed on the site, in a given session.

I have tried different approaches like getting the X and Y position of the clicked element, and later on trigger a click on those x-y coordinates, but theres several problems with this approach. I've also tried to traverse the Dom backwards until i reach the body tag, to build a unike selecter, but this also have it's shortcomings.. The best solution i can think of would be to save what ever $(this) contains.

Comment: You may want to look into something like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) if this is all you're after. I don't know if it can do exactly what you're looking for, but with web apps as complex as they are these days, just recording all of the `click` events probably won't be anywhere near enough to record a full session.

Comment: look into the window object

Comment: If you're looking for a JS solution I'd try PhantomJS

Comment: Yes, saving the `$(this)` is good idea. But if what to check what are the interaction user has done then you have to check that manually in database. As well you can store the url path in db so that you can later find out in which which page which elements are inspected by user.

Comment: @Joe Enos - I'm aware that i will have to support a lot other events than just "click". Will take a look at Selenium :)

Comment: @Rooster could you point me in a direction.. what should i be looking for.. Have already googled for two days but simply can't find out what to look for?

Comment: @EricS.Bullington the problem is that i have no idea how to save, what ever $(this) contains, to the DB. If i alert $(this) i just get [object, object]..

Comment: `$(this)` is just local reference to an executing method's context. You cannot store that in the same since it could be restored. Instead you need a way to uniquely identify the element represented by `this` such as xpath and store that.

Answer (score 1):

If click events are the only thing you want to track, you probably want to add click event handlers to every clickable element on the page.

This would require starting at the `<body>` and walking the DOM, adding handlers as you go.

At the same time, I'd add a new `data-xpath` attribute to each element containing an XPath selector so you can use it in your handler to note the element being clicked, and so replay the user's interaction.

See http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_intro.asp for an introduction to XPath.

Comment: Just to make sure i understand. You suggest that i parse the hole DOM tree and add uniqe identifiers in a custom attribute on all elements?

Comment: Yes, though you need not "parse" the DOM.  Rather, you walk it, starting with the child elements of the body, and add to all clickable elements both the XPath as an attribute and a generic click handler that, on click, reads the attr of $(this) and reports it to your database. In that way, you need not calculate the path to a particular element when it is clicked, which would require a walk back up the DOM, and would be both time intensive and technically problematic.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that makes sense.. But does this mean that i can't simply save $(this) or the content of it to the DB? (I'm guessing that it must contain some sort of uniqe identifyer for the DOM element)

Comment: Clarification: You walk the DOM once, on page load.

Comment: I do not believe DOM elements are uniquely identified in any way you could use to replay events. You'd need to add your own unique id, which is what the XPath selector would be and since XPath selectors can be used to locate unique elements on the page, you can use them to retrigger needed events.

Comment: Also, by adding a timestamp, measured from the initial page load, to your database, you can replay the user's activity with the same inter-event durations.

Comment: A better approach would be to use [jQuery's on handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and calculate the xpath in the handler method.

Comment: See http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2012/09/wicked-good-xpath-faster-javascript.html for a JavaScript XPath implementation.

Comment: @Jay, wouldn't that add significant overhead to each click?

Comment: significantly less than the overhead inured by walking the entire DOM, attaching a handler and storing the xpath of every element on the page.

Comment: @Rasmus, I think you may wish to try both approaches to decide which meets your needs best. I believe extra initial page load time would be preferable from a UX perspective, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: You should also be aware, if you have dynamically loaded elements (after the initial load) those will need to be walked as well. But if using the `on` approach, no additional work is required.

Comment: @Jay, good point. If elements are added to the DOM dynamically, calculating the clicked element's XPath in its click handler would be best.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the comments - i have a clear understanding of what i have to do and research now!

I know you shouldn't be using the comments for thanking (or so it says), but since I'm new on this forum i just wanted to use the opportunity to ask about forum etiquette.. Should I wote up the answer, award some sort of points to good answers or..?

Answer (score 0):

Faling a sleep yesterday i got an idea and ended up with this code today. - It works as intended but I'm guessing that Xpath would perform better!?

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    var parents = target.parents();
    var myParents = '';
    $($(parents).get().reverse()).each(function(key, value){
        var parentIndex = $(this).index()+1;
        myParents += $(this).prop("tagName")+':NTH-CHILD('+parentIndex+') > '; 
    });
    var childIndex = target.index()+1;
    var childTag = target.get(0).tagName;
    myParents += childTag+':NTH-CHILD('+childIndex+')';
    alert(myParents);
});
```

The above code will return a unique selector-string likes this:

```
HTML:NTH-CHILD(1) > BODY:NTH-CHILD(2) > SECTION:NTH-CHILD(1) > UL:NTH-CHILD(1) > LI:NTH-CHILD(3) > A:NTH-CHILD(1)
```

Comment: you're definitely on the right, err, path. :-). Rather than "reinventing the wheel", I'd recommend you use XPath as it is a standard, which means you can can easily share your code with others-and has the added benefit that you don't need to write new code to navigate to elements in the DOM.

Comment: @RobRaisch Thanks for the feedback and confirmation of my approach.  With jQuery and the above code i don't need any additional code to navigate to DOM elements - i can simply do like this:

`$("html:nth-child(1) > body:nth-child(2) > section:nth-child(1) > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)").trigger('click');` 

But i will take your advice in to consideration and try Xpath to.